# C# WPF - Live search in a DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, rowfilter

I have a WPF Browserapplication which gets data stored on a SQL Server, stores it in a DataTable and displays it in a DataGrid. Now I want to have a TextBox where you can search entries in the DataTable but when I load the Application I'm getting an error telling me, that the row [Company] cannot be found.

I think the problem is, that the DataTable isn't yet filled when the filter is being applied to the DataTable. Can someone please give me a hint how to make this working?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    showSQLData();
}

private void showSQLData() 
{
    string sqlConnectionString = @"blabla";
    string sqlCommandString = "SELECT * FROM Excel_import";

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandString, sqlConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        adapter.Fill(dt);

        dataGridSQLData.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
}

private void textBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Company LIKE '%{0}%'", textBoxSearch.Text);
}
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. Obvious question is do you definitely have a Company column in your database? Have you tried explicitly naming your columns in the select rather than using *?

Comment: Yes, The Company column is there. If the filter is applied by a Button and its click event everything is working fine but not when using the TextChanged event of a TextBox. I've made a test query in the Server-Explorer: Select Company FROM Excel_import and this is working so I assume it to be working in the code as well.

Comment: So you get an exception just when the page loads? Or every time you type in the textbox?

Comment: Have you tried checking that `textBoxSearch.Text` is not null or empty before trying to set the `RowFilter`?

Comment: textBoxSearch.Text is not null and the exception occurs directly when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you latest comment I would guess that `textBoxSearch_TextChanged` is being fired from within the `InitializeComponent()` call. You could check that `dt.Rows.Count > 0` in `textBoxSearch_TextChanged` and return if that condition is not met.